# MVC 4 Form Authentication - Cannot access any other action beside the one declared on the web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, form-authentication

This is my settings at web.config:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
```

On my controller I have few actions, on every action I added [AllowAnonymous] decoration, but I'm getting redirection from every action to the Login action.

I even tried to add [AllowAnonymous] decoration to the controller, but it doesn't help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the membership provider node? can you even hit the home controller?

Comment: are you using the cookie based authentication tickets? and how is your routing configured?

Comment: I'm not sure what is membership provider, tried to search it on web.config - didn't find anything. I can get only to the login action on the login controller. Every other request goes to the login action.
I'm using cookie based authentication, and my routing is the default routing.

Comment: Do you have the anonymous authentication disabled in IIS?

Comment: No, form and anonymous authentication are enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the question with better description, and the answer:

[Forms Authentication & authorization MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382950/forms-authentication-authorization-mvc-4/16383041)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by adding the following to my `web.config`

```
<location path="Login">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

I also had to add similar location statements to get my stylesheets, scripts, and images available prior to authentication.

**Edit 1**

I realized that I actually ran into this issue while running my MVC app as an application in a virtual directory, instead of being the base site.  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this problem. Some of our team members had to switch `Specific user` to `Application pool identity` in IIS Authentication settings.

**Anonymous Authentication** enabled

[image: IIS Anonymous Authentication]