# Windows Authentication works for me but not anyone else

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I am trying to convert the authentication for my application from forms authentication to windows authentication.
Having made the conversion and deployed to test server, I find that I have access, but 2 colleagues in the same security group do not. They get to the site, but are prompted for login+password.  The security groups are set up in AD and are used as roles.
I am very confused about this, I am not sure what to do next to try and fix this.
So for more details. My web.config is set as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

The controller containing the first page is set to

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"domain\Role1, domain\Role2, domain\Role3")]
public class ContractController : BaseController
```

(the role names have changed).
Myself and my 2 colleagues are set to Role 3.
IIS on the test server for this project is set to:
[image]

So what else do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: "colleagues do not have access" - in what way?  Do they get to the site, but are prompted for login+password?   Don't get to the site at all?   What do you get if you deploy without the `[Authorize]` attribute?

Comment: Do they get to the site, but are prompted for login+password? Yes, thats what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I found was that the folder where the project has been deployed to needs to have it's security settings reset to include the 3 roles.

Answer (score 3):

You need to disable Anonymous Authentication in this scenario. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28VS.98%29.aspx.

Check there are no spelling mistakes in any Role names (you have Role 3 and Role3 in your example, though I realise that doesn't correspond to the actual code).

Comment: I disabled Anonymous Authentication and have the same problem still.

Comment: Try removing the authorization element in web.config. If you want to give access to authenticated users by default, use a global filter (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16383041/1169670).

Comment: I tried that just now and it did not work. That said, I only want access for AD members that belong to the 3 security groups, that that probably wasn't going to work anyway.

Comment: To ensure that the problem is related to the configuration of your colleagues' accounts, ask them to log in from your machine, or try logging in yourself from theirs. If it is an account issue, I suggest you verify all their role assignments on the domain controller, if you haven't already.

Comment: They can log in to windows on your machine, and then access the site - what I meant

Comment: OK, I see what you mean and a good idea. So I logged in my PC as a colleague and I still could not access the website without a credentials popup appearing.