# Partial views for login can not call differently named action methods in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am building a members' only ASP.NET MVC site that will offer its users more than one way to log in using `FormsAuthentication`. So the idea is that there would be one form for the typical username and password authentication and then another form for a mobile number for electronic certificate authentication.

Now I have read a lot of documentation on how to solve multiple forms in one view and I have now a fairly elegant solution of having one view with two partial views containing the forms and one viewmodel with two model properties. This provides a good solution for validation so each form is validated separately instead of both when pressing the respective submit button.

Here is the code:

Login.cshtml:

```
@model OneMeetingPortal2.Models.ViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="well">
        <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    </div>

@Html.Partial("_LoginUsernamePasswordPartial", Model.UserPass)

@Html.Partial("_LoginMobilePartial", Model.Mobile)

</div>
```

_LoginUsernamePasswordPartial.cshtml:

```
@model OneMeetingPortal2.Models.LoginUsernamePasswordModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @role = "form", @id = "_userNameForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    //Birtingu validation elements er stjórnað með CSS. Sjá .validation-summary-valid í Main.css. Birtist ef villa kemur fram.
    @Html.ValidationSummary("Eftirfarandi villur komu upp:", new { @class = "alert alert-danger col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

_LoginMobilePartial.cshtml. Note that if I change the action name parameter to `Login` I get an error about an ambigious action name:

```
@model OneMeetingPortal2.Models.LoginMobileModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginM", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @role = "form", @id = "_GSMForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary("Eftirfarandi villur komu upp:", new { @class= "alert alert-danger col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MobileNumber, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MobileNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MobileNumber)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And here are the models:

```
 public class ViewModel
    {
        public LoginMobileModel Mobile { get; set; }
        public LoginUsernamePasswordModel UserPass { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginUsernamePasswordModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Ekki má sleppa notandanafni.")]
        [Display(Name = "Notandanafn")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Notandanafnið má ekki vera lengra en 50 stafir")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Notandanafnið verður að vera a.m.k. 3 stafir")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Ekki má sleppa lykilorði.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Lykilorð")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage="Lykilorðið má ekki vera lengra en 50 stafir")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage="Lykilorðið verður að vera a.m.k. 3 stafir")]
        public string Password { get; set; }  
    }

    public class LoginMobileModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ekki má sleppa símanúmeri.")]
        [Display(Name = "Farsímanúmer")]
        [StringLength(7, ErrorMessage = "Símanúmer má ekki vera lengra en 7 stafir.")]
        [MinLength(7, ErrorMessage = "Símanúmer má ekki vera styttra en 7 stafir.")]
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

And then the Controller methods:

```
        // GET: /Account/Login
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ViewModel m = new ViewModel();
            m.Mobile = new LoginMobileModel();
            m.UserPass = new LoginUsernamePasswordModel();
            return View(m);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginUsernamePasswordModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (_accountService.Login(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    string xmlString = _accountService.GetEmployeeDetails(model.UserName);
                    Session.Add("ProfileXml", xmlString);
                    Classes.Profile profile = new Classes.Profile(xmlString);
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(profile.Subject, false);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ViewModel m = new ViewModel();
            m.UserPass = model;
            m.Mobile = new LoginMobileModel();
            return View(m);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LoginM(LoginMobileModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                MobileLoginReturn mlr = _accountService.LoginGSM(model.MobileNumber);
                if(mlr.Error == null)
                {
                    Session.Add("ProfileXml", mlr.EmployeeXmlString);
                    Classes.Profile profile = new Classes.Profile(mlr.EmployeeXmlString);
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(profile.Subject, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", mlr.Error.Message);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);

        }
```

However I get a weird behavior that seems to be connected only to the login page. I would like to have two different action methods called `LoginUserPass` and `LoginMobile` but I can't. The actions will simply not be called if I name them thus. Funnily enough when I set up the same scheme elsewhere in the site after authentication, for example in the Home controller everything works fine and I can call different action methods in the controller based on the action name parameter in the partial views, for example I can have:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginMobile", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @role = "form", @id = "_GSMForm" }))
{
      [Code omitted]
}
```

and

```
public ActionResult LoginMobile(LoginMobileModel model, string returnUrl){ ... }
```

in the controller.

So, right now, I have to let the first parameter name in one of the the partial views be Login so the Login action method will be called. There can only be two methods with that name in the controller, one for get and one for post, if more I get the ambiguous method exception. So at the moment I am faced with the fact that I have to choose if I want to let the user log in using mobile number OR Username and password, for I can not have both methods available on the login page. That of course is not acceptable, surely there is a way to have both, right?

I hope someone knows how to solve this dilemma. Does this have something to be do with FormsAuthentication?

Comment: I am sorry for so simple answer, could you please  try use  FormMethod.Post for your methods. Because When you try send form data via Get it can direct for many strange troubles. Correct me if I am wrong and it doesn't help.

Comment: Ah, I see that I made a mistake in the partial view code _LoginMobilePartial. The third parameter is supposed to be FormMethod.Post. I will fix that and in the controller method that I posted. I have fixed in code in VS but it made no difference. The problem persists unchanged.

Comment: Could you please add notes from browser console if you try send LoginUserPass or LoginMobile. For example if request ends with 500 err it is one point, but if it can't even found controllers method it's another(for example you forgot add allow anonymys attribute for you action, or maybe model can't be de-serialized with data you've send. Best regards.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly is your issue? There's nothing wrong with what you have now. The form where you pass "Login" will call the `Login` action and the form where you pass "LoginM", will call the `LoginM` action. Seems that would be what you would want, as nothing else really makes sense.

Comment: As I understand the issue fires when he tries rename Login and LoginM.

Comment: Hi Роман Иванов,
Please see screenshot here where I try to call LoginMobile: http://screencast.com/t/Hrfaobzia9I

Comment: Chris Pratt 
Yes, this should work, but it doesn't, hence my question if this might have something to do with FormsAuthentication. 

So if  I try to clarify the question further: Why do my forms in partial views not trigger the correct action methods in the controller if they are called anything other than Login (name of the view holding the partial views). This seems to only apply to a login form using forms authentication. Everything is fine on other pages after authentication.

Comment: Seems here you could find solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608766/post-a-form-with-multiple-partial-views Hope it helps. Best regards. If it will be helpfull first I have seen screenshot and find that it is not 500 but 302 error(so request can't find an action). So wek now that point is in Model parameters(maybe) I have asked google about it and get a link.

Comment: Thank you @РоманИванов. I have tried switching out the PartialViews out for EditorTemplates. The form is working like before. the form appears but when I try to log in with username and password and the action method's name is anything other than Login it does not get called. Please see screencast: [screencast](http://screencast.com/t/ugJOu6275R2P)

The login.cshtml now contains:<br/>

'@Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserPass)'<br />

'@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Mobile)' <br />

instead of the call to '@Html.Partial' before.

Comment: If it is not secret project maybe you can load it in bitbucket I can check it on my side) If it is not possible could you try off jquery validation and try send request again. At the past I've had some troubles - also check your mark up in browser. Maybe it render forms in the wrong way - if it is - try fix it.

Comment: @РоманИванов
I think I have just managed to prove that this issue is caused by FormsAuthentication. When I comment out the 'authentication' and 'authorization' nodes in 'web.config' I managed to get the log-in forms to call correctly named action methods in the controller. Also I managed to make sure only one validation summary would show up if an error occurs by following this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342427/specify-validation-summary-on-multiple-forms). Now I just have to figure out if it is possible to use FormsAuthentication and if yes, how.

Answer (score 0):

When I finally figured out that it was FormsAuthentication that was causing this behavior I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382950/forms-authentication-authorization-mvc-4/16383041)

In short delete the `<authorization>` node from `web.config` and then in `FilterConfig.cs` add `filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());`